Hybridisation and MOT (co-existence)
So, hybridisation theory says "Atomic orbitals of same elements combine to form hybrid orbitals and it is involved in bonding with other elements ". Now MOT says "atomic orbitals of different elements combine to form bonds"




Both are used to understand bonding, so i wondered if both could co-exist, and i had an idea "atomic orbitals of same atom combine to form atomic hybrid orbitals and hybrid orbitals of different atoms combine to form molecular orbitals"
but as in my book, for MOT it says, 'atomic orbitals' combine not mentioning anything about hybrids...


what actually happens here ?

Hybridisation is a mental construct, it only exists in our head.

The number of coexisting theoretical models of reality is limited only by resources and imagination of scientists.

Well, i got what i wanted.

Hybridisation is not a theory, it's a tool coming from valence bond theory. As Ivan already said, is a mental construct, a mathematical description. Please also include citation to the quote you are using in this question.

right... i was unsure of that so i simply used 'hybridisation theory'


atomic orbitals of same atom combine to form atomic hybrid orbitals
and hybrid orbitals of different atoms combine to form molecular
orbitals

I can see no reason in principle why you can't do this - choosing a basis of "hybrid" orbitals for the MO calculation is really no different from any other choice, assuming no major issue with something like completeness that I can't immediately see. I can just see no practical advantage over just using the AOs (or something that looks a bit like them) directly. For instance hybrid orbitals typically require some knowledge of the local geometry surrounding an atom, and the basis will have to be adjusted for each case - but you don't need to do this if just stating with the AOs since the MO calculation will effectively automatically do it for you.

The basis set of valance bond theory uses hybrid orbitals (more or less, it's complicated). This is quite a popular theory, which is also equivalent to MO theory (at their respective limit).

There is no direct solution to the Schrodinger equation for molecules - as a result we can't exactly give 1 model. So we use 2. (note: at their retrospective limits, the models are equivalent). The molecular orbital theory yields molecular orbitals from LCAO delocalized across the entire molecule. One thing we can do is to perform a localization scheme - a unitary transformation through addition and subtraction of delocalized molecular orbitals which yields localized molecular orbitals still equivalent to the standard delocalized molecular orbitals but concentrated more between bonds like our standard Lewis structure models. A great example is Intrinsic bonding orbitals or IBOs. When you look at the IBOs of water, you will see HUGE resemblance to hybridized orbitals. Both theories also cannot co-exist - they are equivalent in their retrospective limits.
Another localization scheme  giving very similar results are natural bonding orbitals. You can find a lot about these with some research online.
Note: There is no implications that the actual physical process of mixing orbitals to form hybridized orbitals exists or is feasible.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_bond_orbitals (link)

Note that Schrodinger equation for a molecule can be solved numerically, just not analytically. It quickly gets prohibitively difficult, but still possible, at least in principle.

Both theories also cannot co-exist - they are equivalent in their retrospective limits. I don't get this. I'd they are equivalent at their limit, further that men that they are equally valid and hence coexist? That at least is my interpretation. And the same thing I've always taught about valence bond theory and molecular orbital theory; which do perfectly well coexist.
